# How to get the ID of newly created backup using "Cloud SQL Admin API" with Python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am writing a script using *Cloud SQL Admin API*'s *backupRuns* instance which has the following methods:

```
1. delete(project=*, instance=*, id=*)
2. get(project=*, instance=*, id=*)
3. insert(project=*, instance=*, body=*)
4. list(project=*, instance=*, maxResults=None, pageToken=None) 
5. list_next(previous_request=*, previous_response=*)
```

Here's the link to the API: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sqladmin/v1beta4/python/latest/sqladmin_v1beta4.backupRuns.html

What I find strange in the API is the *insert()* method, when we insert/create a new backup calling this method of the API, it returns the following response :

```
{'insertTime': '2018-12-26T06:48:35.675Z',
 'kind': 'sql#operation',
 'name': 'some-random-string,
 'operationType': 'BACKUP_VOLUME',
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project-name/operations/some-random-string',
 'status': 'PENDING',
 'targetId': 'cloud-instance-name',
 'targetLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project-name/instances/cloud-instance-name',
 'targetProject': 'project-name',
 'user': 'some-user@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'}
```

This seems like an asynchronous call in which *status* changes from *PENDING* to *SUCCESSFUL* after a few seconds. Now if I want to keep on checking the instance until its status is *SUCCESSFUL*, I'll need the *_id_* of the newly created instance (to call the *get()* method). 
 
 The only way I could figure out is calling the *list()* method and checking the *enqueuedTime* of the list items with the *insertTime* of the response above and get the id, then call the *get()* method for the status.
It feels like a hack to me, is there a better way to watch for the status until it is *SUCCESSFUL*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google API treats every request as an operation which can be retrieved from the **operations()** of service built from **googleapiclient.discovery**. For example :

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

service = discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4')

#Just insert a backup for an SQL instance or any other operation
insert_response = service.backupRuns().insert(project=<project-id>,instance=<instance-id>, body={}).execute()

#Get the opepration to check the status
insert_operation = service.operations().get(project=<project-id>,operation=insert_response['name']).execute()
```

This `insert_opertation` can be used to check the current status of the operation.

Here how `insert_response` and `insert_operation` look:

```
print(insert_response)
{'insertTime': '2019-01-08T13:04:31.941Z',                                                                                                                              
 'kind': 'sql#operation',                                                                                                                                               
 'name': '<unique-name-of-the-operation>',                                                                                                                        
 'operationType': 'BACKUP_VOLUME',                                                                                                                                      
 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project-id>/operations/<unique-name-of-the-operation>',                                                
 'startTime': '2019-01-08T13:04:32.052Z',                                                                                                                               
 'status': 'RUNNING',                                                                                                                                                   
 'targetId': '<instance-name>',                                                                                                                                   
 'targetLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project-id>/instances/<instance-name>',                                                              
 'targetProject': '<project-id>',                                                                                                                                           
 'user': '<user>'}

print(insert_operation)
{'endTime': '2018-12-26T13:07:08.746Z',
'enqueuedTime': '2018-12-26T13:06:33.563Z',
'id': '<operation-id>',
'instance': '<instance-name>',
'kind': 'sql#backupRun',
'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project-id>/instances/<instance-name>/backupRuns/<operation-id>',
'startTime': '2018-12-26T13:06:33.563Z',
'status': 'SUCCESSFUL',
'type': 'ON_DEMAND',
'windowStartTime': '2018-12-26T13:06:33.563Z'}
```

`service.operations().get()` can be used to get any operation performed using the APIs which return a `name` in the response.

Refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#building-and-calling-a-service) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found this API also confusing. The `insert` method returns a `sql#operation` object and it has a GUID-type `id`-field. The `list` and `get` methods use `sql#backupRun` object and they have `id` with datatype long. I have not found any way to map these.

You could use the `description` field to identify your backupRun. It is not optimal, but could work for you. Specify a unique value in `description` field in your insert method body parameter. You can then filter the list method result with the description and possibly also filter type='ON_DEMAND' in addition to the enqueuedTime. The list result is in reverse chronological order so you should find the right item in the beginning of the list.

There is an `id` parameter in documentation for `insert` methods `body` parameter but setting it will raise an error. The API is still in beta. Hope this API matures and changes so that we can have linking from inserts to get.

Comment: I have figured out the API to do the needful and mentioned that in my own answer. Please have a look.